# Lists with multiple 'nested' items

Tags: r

Really basic question but I can't find an answer - I've probably misunderstood lists in R

Can you have multiple 'nested' items held in a list?
This is fine:

```
cats<-c("red", "blue", "yellow")
l1<-list()

for(i in cats){
  l1[i][1]<-"hello"
};l1
```

This is not:

```
for(i in cats){
  l1[i][2]<-"goodbye"
};l1
```

The output I have in mind would mean

`l1$red[1]` is `"hello"` and `l1$red[2]` is `"goodbye"`

Am I setting the list up incorrectly? Or is the entire concept flawed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the list elements with `[[` instead of `[`:

```
for(i in cats){
  l1[[i]][1]<-"hello"
};l1

for(i in cats){
  l1[[i]][2]<-"goodbye"
};l1


> l1$red[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[1] "hello"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> l1$red[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[1] "goodbye"
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the) post which is about how to access list elements.

Comment: That's it - thank you. It actually turns out I wanted l1[[i]][[1]]<-"hello" and l1[[i]][[2]]<-"goodbye".  This answer got me there.

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```
cats<-c("red", "blue", "yellow")
words <- c("hello", "goodbye")
```

You can create the list with this command:

```
l1 <- setNames(rep(list(words), length(cats)), cats)


> l1
$red
[1] "hello"   "goodbye"

$blue
[1] "hello"   "goodbye"

$yellow
[1] "hello"   "goodbye"

> l1$red[1]
[1] "hello"

> l1$red[2]
[1] "goodbye"
```

Comment: Thank you - hadn't seen this approach before